# how to skip the default JWT token Authentication provided with superset? I want to access the API without passing JWT token

Tags: jwt, apache-superset

We have our own authentication service which we want use to secure the Superset Rest APIs and want to skip the default JWT token Authentication provided with superset.
How can I skip the default JWT token Authentication provided with superset?

Comment: Just winging it completely here, but creating a user "public" with the permissions you want everyone authenticated by your third party system to have and setting `PUBLIC_ROLE_LIKE = "public"` in superset_config.py would seem it could work to disable the built-in authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Below steps worked for me but only I am able to access to Get APIs without passing JWT Token. I am geeting a error when i try to create a dataset.

- Set PUBLIC_ROLE_LIKE: Optional[str] = 'Alpha' or PUBLIC_ROLE_LIKE:
  Optional[str] = 'Gamma'  in
  /home/{user}/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/superset/config.py
  file.
- Add datasource access Permissions in public role  'All Datasource
  Access on all_datasource_access'
- Re-launch superset with superset init

Post: http://127.0.0.1:8088/api/v1/dataset/

Request: {
"database": 3,
"schema": "nrpexamqa",
"table_name": "qti_test"
}

Comment: This is quite dangerous if your Superset is public